# Access Genius Bar history and notes online?

Tags: icloud, apple-store

I just had a Genius Bar appointment where the very helpful *bartender(?)* made some notes about the problem I was having. He said that the info would be emailed to me at my associated email address. I never got an email at that address... nor did I at my iCloud address.

Is there a place online that I can log into where I can access my Genius Bar history and notes?

Comment: I found this: https://supportprofile.apple.com but since there was no repair done on the device, it doesn't appear that there is any more info aside from the date I brought it in.

Answer (score 1):

Today (with some recent changes to the apple.com web site) You can access basic repair data at:

- https://checkrepair.apple.com

Once you sign in, you may find that some case notes are not associated with your AppleID depending on how you initiated service and what was typed into the repair database system.

The functionality at https://supportprofile.apple.com also is spotty recently, but in the past that was a reliable source of repair and ownership information of devices registered to a specific Apple ID.

In general, the answer to your question is No - the full contents of Apple's repair database is only accessible to people that are trained in Apple's privacy policies. Your detailed notes also are not generally available to you - just summary information about some cases. If you need more data than you can access, contact AppleCare - online, phone or the genius bar to retrieve a case history and/or request information from case notes.

In specific, businesses can get added details through the [Joint Venture](https://jointventure.apple.com/services/home) program or as a [self-servicing AppleCare](https://www.apple.com/support/programs/ssa/) account. Both cost money whether you pay annually or have 1,000 deployed devices across your business.

Comment: Also, over time this system gets broken as it appears to be today. I have dozens of computers with repair history and the web form only shows the last iPhone service I received. Your best bet might be to try the above and then contact a human to explain what you need.